# Add array of components as property

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm learning Angular 2. In order for that I'm creating a component which should receive as parameter in its attributes an array of other components.

Here is my code so far:

```
<card
  [actions]='[<icon name="tick"></icon>]'
>
  <span>Example</span>
</card>
```

In this case, to my component `Card` I'm trying to send an array, (in this case of just one component) of another component.

This is not working. How should I fix that?

### EDIT

What I'm trying to do, is to render inside that card component the `actions` components in one part of the component, and `ng-content` in other part of the component

Answer (score 0):

That's not gonna work. `<icon name="tick"></icon>` can be treated as HTML and added like `<div [innerHTML]="someHtml">` but this isn't going to become a component.

[Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468) shows a way how this could be done in Angular2.

Comment: Maybe I'm asking wrong. What I need to do, is to add an html, which inside the object, should be rendered in other part that the `ng-content`

Comment: If you want to add HTML you have to add ot to a template of a component and then add the component. If you add HTML from a string `<icon>` directly it will not become an `IconComponent` and bindings like `[name]` are not processed by Angular..